# Querying my own google API yields unexpected error 403

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk

Following the official documentation, I set up a google API and now I am struggeling to query it from PowerShell using the Google Cloud SDK and certificates.

I have the following PowerShell script (as provided by the [Google form parser documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser)):

```
$cred = gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $cred" }

Invoke-WebRequest `
  -Method POST `
  -Headers $headers `
  -ContentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
  -InFile request.json `
   -Uri "https://eu-documentai.googleapis.com/v1beta3/projects/299792458/locations/eu/processors/4711:process" | Select-Object -Expand Content
```

Project and processor ID (`299792458` and `4711`) are just dummy values here, but I did indeed use the correct ones.

My error message reads

```
Invoke-WebRequest : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
At C:\Users\b--rian\CallLcapFormParser.ps1:4 char:1
 + Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Headers $headers  -ContentType: "appl ...
 + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

This sounds like the address is not publically exposed, which is suprising to me.

#### Background

I do have a file `request.json` in the same directory as the script, looking as follows:

```
{
 "document": {
   "mimeType": "image/png",
   "content": "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"
   }
}
```

I followed [Authenticating as a service account](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production) to set up authentication using `gcloud`, e.g. by setting `$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\b--rian\myCert.json"`. The fact that the first two lines of the PowerShell execute without error means that authentication should not be the issue.

Here is the steps I performed so far in the Cloud Console:

1. Within my project, I created a processor which I can successfully query manually:
   [image: FormParserProcessor]
2. Also created a service account and a corresponding key , both using default settings, which presumably means, that the service account should have the correct user roles:
   [image: ServiceAccountOverview]
   I am sorry that the screenshot is in German, but I guess you can get the point by the general layout. (The issue why my cloud console language is fluctuating between English and German will be a separate question.)

Comment: 403 is not a can't be found error but an access denied error.  It received your credentials but did not like them

Comment: @ScottHeath So you are saying that my certificate might be incorrect? I was assuming that associating the processor (providing the API-URL) with the service account goes wrong, meaning that service account is not allowed to access the URL.

Comment: Which type of authorization does your API require (OAuth Access Token or OAuth Identity Token)?

Comment: @JohnHanley I see where you are heading, but I am not sure which. Maybe *you* can deduce that from [Google Cloud Service Account Docu](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#service_account_keys).

Comment: I am not sure why you are providing me that link. The key question is "what kind of authorization are you using"? You set something up, but your question is lacking details.

Comment: @JohnHanley Well, differently put: How can I figure out, what type of authorization my Google API requires? I don't remember that I chose between those two options. I am totally new to Google Cloud, and I provided everything I considered useful or related, so I am very grateful for hints.

Comment: Your question title "my own google API". By reviewing the URI parameter I can see that you are using Google Document AI. Very different things. What roles have you assigned to the service account that you are using? Read this link to understand how to get setup. https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/setup